# What does 'current context' means for generator-expressions?

Tags: cmake

Regarding generator-expressions of type 'Multi-level Expression Evaluation', such as `$<GENEX_EVAL:expr>`, the CMake [manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.27/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#multi-level-expression-evaluation) states the following:

> Content of expr evaluated as a generator expression in the current
> context.

What does 'current context' means, in this case?

Comment: From my understanding, "current context" means that if your `$<GENEX_EVAL>` expression is part of the some **target**'s property, then `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:prop>` expression will be evaluated to the property of that target. However, following example `$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:foo,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,CUSTOM_KEYS>>` for `$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL>` looks strange: why they repeat `foo` twice. Need some testing...

Comment: @Tsyvarev - That would make sense. I wonder why they chose the wording "current context" vs something like "affected target".